# Expectation of the product of two observations of geometric brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I would like to calculate $$\mathbb{E} \left(X_s X_t \right), s < t $$ where the $X_t$ is an exponential martingale or geometric brownian motion:

$$ X_t = X_0 \exp\left[\int_0^t \sigma(u) d W(u) - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t \sigma^2(u)du\right]$$

Is my derivation that it equal to $X_0^2$ correct? I am not sure about my last equality where I am using the fact that the expression is a martingale and that brownian motion increments are independent: $$\mathbb{E} \left(X_s X_t \right) = X_0^2\mathbb{E}\left(\exp\left[\int_0^s \sigma(u) d W(u) - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^s \sigma^2(u)du + \int_0^t \sigma(u) d W(u) - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t \sigma^2(u)du \right] \right)
=  X_0^2\mathbb{E}\left(\exp\left[2\int_0^s \sigma(u) d W(u) - \int_0^s \sigma^2(u)du\right] \exp\left[ \int_s^t \sigma(u) d W(u) - \frac{1}{2} \int_s^t \sigma^2(u)du \right] \right)
\\= X_0^2$$

Comment: It is not correct. But almost. For the first exponential term in the last line you should use that the expectation is $\mathbb E[e^{Y-\operatorname{Var}(Y)/2}]=1$ when $Y\sim N(0,V)\,.$ What is your $Y$ in this case? And what is its variance?